# Create selector from existing selector

Tags: ngrx, angular15, ngrx-selectors

I'm updating my Angular 14 to 15. In my app we have a selector like

```
export const selectPlaces = createSelector(
  locations, //Feature selector
  (state) => state?.locations
);
```

Then I need to get another key value from locations say it as 'gardens'

```
export const selectGardens = createSelector(
  selectPlaces,
  (state) => state?.gardens
);
```

In Angular version 14 I can do this, but not in Angular 15. Error is

```
MemoizedSelector<object, IState | undefined, (s1: IState ) => IState | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '[SelectorWithProps<unknown, unknown, IState >, SelectorWithProps<unknown, unknown, unknown>, SelectorWithProps<unknown, unknown, unknown>, ... 4 more ..., SelectorWithProps<...>]
```

I have selectors with multiple selectors as parameters. How can I solve this?